# Is it possible to reference the key in the value when creating a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to define a dictionary as follows:

```
dict = {
    Player: $key.Name + " takes some action"
}
```

Is there a syntax that would allow me to do this?

I want to avoid using `Player` twice. For example, if I want to replace `Player` with `AdvancedPlayer`, I have two references to replace.

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you want to do, but if you were to drop the `$` that would be valid python syntax

Comment: You may want to write a class instead with a function that's something like `getPlayerName()`. Just a suggestion I'm not sure exactly what you're wanting to do.

Comment: Also, I don't suggest using `dict` as a name, as it is a built-in. Never use built-ins (such as `dict`, `list`, `str`, `tuple`, etc) as variable names (general programming etiquette.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Player(object): 
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

p1 = Player("bernard")
p2 = Player("hoagie")

t = (p1, p2, ...)
d = {p: p.name + " something something" for p in t}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Dictionary comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-dictionary-comprehension) may help.

```
>>> players = ["Mark", "Jack", "John"]
>>> player_dict = {k: k + " takes some action" for k in players}
>>> player_dict
{'John': 'John takes some action', 'Jack': 'Jack takes some action', 'Mark': 'Mark takes some action'}
```

They take the form `{`*key*`:` *value* `for` *variable* `in` [*iterable*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)`}`

Answer (score 0):

IT sounds like you want to use the key you are creating in the value assigned to that key. Yes this is possible:

```
playerDict = {Player: Player + " takes some action"}
```

Comment: What I wanted to do was avoid using "Player" twice

Comment: @Shagglez why? That is how you do it

Comment: what if I want to replace `Player` with `AdvancedPlayer`? I have two references to replace

Answer (score 0):

The question to me means something different than what the code suggests, that is: you want to reference the dictionary key in its value *in the same context* in which you create the dictionary.

You can do that with the walrus (`:=`) operator (from Python 3.8):

```py
d = {
    (k := "key"): f"Value + {k}"
}
print(d)
```

```
{'key': 'Value + key'}
```